# Where to find large stock Android drawables?

Tags: android, resize, stock

Just as the title says.  I know there are drawables in android.R.drawables, but because they are so small, they look horrible when scaled up.  Does anyone know where I can find the current 4.x drawables that are larger than the ones in the folder?

Since I don't know much about drawables anyways, are the stock drawables in android.R.drawables all in a single size, or are there multiple versions to support different density screens?  If so, how can I access these larger drawables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know where I can find the current 4.x drawables that are larger than the ones in the folder?

If you mean larger than the `-xhdpi` ones, they are probably on some graphic designer's workstation at Google.

> are the stock drawables in android.R.drawables all in a single size, or are there multiple versions to support different density screens?

They ship in multiple densities.

> If so, how can I access these larger drawables?

They are in your SDK directory, in `platforms/$VERSION/data/res/`, where `$VERSION` is one of the available API levels that you have installed.

Comment: @TheObscureQuestion: The icon sizes in pixels should be in accordance to the icon size guidelines, which will vary a bit by the use of the icon (launcher vs. action bar item vs. ...).